# mongo db need to traverse each element in array and convert underlying type

Tags: mongodb

I need to traverse each element in an array and convert there type to number from string. I am not able to convert it to Mongo shell. Could anyone please guide me.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e9aabb1f9420ce8c8efe282"),
    "description" : "base 1"
    "title" : "You received a new 3",
    "uniq" : [ 
        "12345"
    ],
    "created" : "2020-03-16T11:23:45.172Z"
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e9aabb1f9420ce8c8efe283"),
    "description" : "base 1"
    "title" : "You received a new 2",
    "uniq" : [ 
        "34321"
    ],
    "created" : "2020-03-14T11:23:45.172Z"
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e9aabb1f9420ce8c8efe284"),
    "description" : "base 3"
    "title" : "You received a new 1",
    "uniq" : [ 
        "34328"
    ],
    "created" : "2020-03-15T11:23:45.172Z"
}
```

I have tried the following.

```
db.getCollection('noti').find({}).forEach(function(myDoc) { 
    var val = myDoc._id
   db.getCollection('noti').updateOne({ 
        "_id": val}, 
        {"$set":  {
            "uniq": [ new Number(myDoc.uniq) ]
        }
     })
})
```

need to convert uniq ["xxxx"] to uniq [Int] and update it in Mongo database

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MongoDB 4.2, you can do that in an update:

```
db.collection.updateMany( {}, [
        {$set: {uniq: {$convert:{
                              input: "$uniq",
                              to: "int",
                              onError: "valueToUseIfConversionFails"
        }}}}
])
```

Comment: its not working. Failed to execute script.

Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators 
Details:
DBCollection.prototype.updateMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:625:1
@(shell):1:1

Comment: That sounds like an older version of MongoDB.  What version are you running?